# I am Dominican citizen, I am travelling to Botswana from DOH-JNB-GBE do i need a transit visa in JNB?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit-visas, south-africa, dominican-citizens

I am Dominican citizen, I am travelling to Botswana from DOH-JNB-GBE. Do I need a transit visa in JNB (O. R. Tambo International Airport, South Africa)?

Answer (score 2):

According to the website of the South African Consulate in the US, [Transit Visa - 3 Days or less](https://www.southafrica-newyork.net/homeaffairs/transit_visa.htm) you do not need a transit visa.  From that link:

> Travelers transiting through the following international airports are
>   exempted from/do not have to be in possession of transit visas, but
>   will be subjected to biometric capturing directly at the airport:
>
> 1. OR Tambo International;
> 2. Cape Town International;
> 3. King Shaka;
> 4. Lanseria (Johannesburg)
>
> Please note that the above-mentioned exemption does not apply to
>   deportees. Please also note that foreigners who are utilizing land
>   ports of entry to transit through the Republic of South Africa and who
>   are subject to South Africa visa control should apply for and be
>   issued with port of entry visas.

So if you were using a land port of entry you *would* need a transit visa